# Dynamics AX MorphX WMSPickingList Report

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I am trying to modify the WMSPickingList_OrderPick Report in Dynamics AX 2009.

I am attempting to move the InventDim group onto the same line as the actual Item Line, as it currently prints underneath.

I have tried manually moving the fields, in this case no data appears.
I have tried switching the parameters so that the item dimensions appear after or a part of the item number, in this case it still appears below.
I have also attemped to simply pick up the values in the Fetch statement and pass them to variables, I can see the values being picked up but on returning them in a display method no data appears?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Accounts receivables > Setups > Forms > Forms Setup
In the "General" tab > "Print item dimensions" group, Select the "Print item dimensions" as "After item number"
I am assuming it is currently set to "Under item line"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assist. We do not use this module but we use Stock Management to run off the picking list when our van drivers request parts for their personal stocks. In this case I needed to hardcode it onto the first line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with WMSPickingList_OrderPick report is the width of the design, the design doesnt have enough width to print the Inventory Dimensions, they dont appear when u put them in the same line because the columns overlap.
However, one very clean solution can be to use a Display method as datasource for the Item ID (i.e item number) and in that display method just append the dimension.